# Cant return the head of a list

Tags: f#

I'm simply trying to retrieve the head from a list, but I'm getting an error that states `The type 'Government' is not compatible with the type 'seq<government>'.`

```
type Government = {
    Id : Id;
    Name : string;
    Abbreviation : string;
    ParentId : string option;
}

type GovernmentStructure<'gov> = 
    | Root of Government : 'gov * SubGov : GovernmentStructure<'gov> list
    | Node of Government : 'gov * SubGov : GovernmentStructure<'gov> list
    | Leaf of Government : 'gov

let rec findGovernment (gov : Government) (governmentStructure : GovernmentStructure<Government> list) =

    [
        for x in governmentStructure do
            match x with
            | Root(gov', subGov) ->
                 if gov = gov' then yield gov' else yield! findGovernment gov subGov
            | Node(gov', subGov) ->
                 if gov = gov' then yield gov' else yield! findGovernment gov subGov
            | Leaf(gov') ->
                 if gov = gov' then yield gov'
    ] |> List.head // This is where I get the error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findGovernment` returns a single item (the one returned from `List.head`), not a collection. Consequently, you want to use `yield` when invoking it recursively, not `yield!`:

```
let rec findGovernment (gov : Government)
                       (governmentStructure : GovernmentStructure<Government> list) =
    [
        for x in governmentStructure do
            match x with
            | Root(gov', subGov) ->
                if gov = gov' then yield gov' else yield findGovernment gov subGov
            | Node(gov', subGov) ->
                if gov = gov' then yield gov' else yield findGovernment gov subGov
            | Leaf(gov') ->
                if gov = gov' then yield gov'
    ] |> List.head
```

Comment: Yes, and also I had to enclose the function and it's arguments in parentheses as yield (findGovernment gov subGov) for it to work, which is what initially threw me off.  Not sure why that is.

Comment: @user1206480 : It compiles cleanly without parenthesis [here](https://ideone.com/wSIsGh)...

Answer (score 3):

Think about this: what return type does your `findGovernment` function have?

If you look at the whole statement, then one would expect it to be `Government` - since you're returning the result of calling `List.head` on something that is presumably a `Government list`.

However, if you look inside the list definition, there is a line `yield! findGovernment ...`. Since the `yield!` instruction expects the argument to be of type `seq<_>`, it follows that `findGovernment` must return a sequence of something.

So what does it return after all? A single `Government` or a sequence thereof? The compiler can't decide for you, so it complains.

I think your mistake is overengineering.
First, let's just think of the problem: for `Root` and `Node` cases, the result is that node if it matches, otherwise the result is somewhere in `SubGov`; and for the `Leaf` case, the result is that leaf if it matches.
Let's write that down:

```
match x with
| Root(g, _) | Node(g, _) when g = gov -> g
| Root(_,sub) | Node(_, sub) -> findGovernment gov sub
| Leaf g when g = gov -> g
```

But wait, now we immediately see a hole in this algorithm: what if the lookup value is not in the structure at all? What should the function return then? There are actually two options: return `Government option`, indicating that there may not be a return value, or just crash. Let's make it crash for simplicity, for now:

```
match x with
| Root(g, _) | Node(g, _) when g = gov -> g
| Root(_,sub) | Node(_, sub) -> findGovernment gov sub
| Leaf g when g = gov -> g
| _ -> failwith "Can't find it."
```

But now, look closer: every time you return something, you are doing it only after comparing that something to `gov`. In other words, the only value this function can return is a value that is equal to `gov`. So the question is: why not just return `gov`?

```
let findGovernment gov = gov
```

I know, this seems silly, but that's the point: if you take your logic to the ultimate conclusion, and that conclusion turns out to be silly, that means that there was something wrong with the logic to begin with.